# Why do i get a warning for creating basic class?

Tags: c++

I created this but i am getting linking errors but i don't know why...

**SysInfo.h**

```
#include <iostream>

class SysInfo 
{

  public:
    SysInfo();
    ~SysInfo();

  private:

};
```

**SysInfo.cpp**

```
#include "SysInfo.h"

using namespace std;

SysInfo::SysInfo()
{
  cout << "Object is being created" << endl;
} 

SysInfo::~SysInfo()
{
  cout << "Object is being deleted" << endl;
}
```

**Main**

```
#include <tchar.h>
#include "Sysinfo.h" 

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    SysInfo inf;
    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

**Message**

```
warning C4930: 'SysInfo inf(void)': prototyped function not called (was a variable definition intended?)
```

The issue is solved. The code you see is corrected code. I changed `#include <SysInfo.h>`
 to `#include "SysInfo.h"` and turned off the pre compile setting in visual studio 2012. That was giving errors ass well.

Comment: What is the linking error?

Comment: SysInfo inf() (getting warning) SysInfo() (linking error)

Comment: [Most Vexing Parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse) Problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SysInfo inf();` is a declaration of function `inf`, returning `SysInfo` class.

Should be `SysInfo inf;`

`#include <SysInfo.h>` is a possible source of concern too. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593/what-is-the-difference-between-include-filename-and-include-filename) for the additional info.

Comment: then i get luinking error :error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall SysInfo::~SysInfo(void)" (??1SysInfo@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function __catch$??0CMainFrame@@QAE@XZ$0 and error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall SysInfo::SysInfo(void)" (??0SysInfo@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function __catch$??0CMainFrame@@QAE@XZ$0

Comment: Is `SysInfo.cpp` file included in the project? It looks like you are providing only class declaration for the compiler.

Comment: yes SysInfo.cpp is included in the project

Comment: Then we need a [mcve].

Comment: @default explane?

Comment: The code i show is the code i got :) but i fixed it by changing the include from #include <SysInfo.h> to #include "SysInfo.h" and turning off the precompile settings

Answer (score 1):

`SysInfo inf();` is a function declaration! A method named `inf` that takes nothing and returns `SysInfo`.

Do this to declare object of `SysInfo`: `SysInfo inf;`

Answer (score 0):

Because your constructor have not any parameters, so you should replace :

```
int main()
{
    SysInfo inf;
}
```

with bellow :

```
int main()
{
    SysInfo inf();
}
```

so try with `SysInfo inf` without `()`.

Comment: There are two answers already explaining exactly this

Comment: @Default because, i had preparing the answer and it takes a little time.